# Angular9: Getting Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a simple app to call backend services using HttpClientModule,, but  data is not showing into the log, I did the following steps and I am using angular-9

could you please check the code.

Thanks in Advance.

1. app.module file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {RestAPIServices} from './services/rest-api.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [RestAPIServices],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. model.ts

```
export class Employee{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    gender:string;
    email? :string; // ? means optional property
    mobile:string;
    department:string;
    isActive:boolean;
    photo? :string;
}
```

3. service.ts

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';

@Injectable()
export class RestAPIServices{

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}

   getEmployee():Observable<Employee[]>{
    //this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>("http://127.0.0.1/angularCRUDservices/user/getEmployees").subscribe(res=>  console.log(res));
    return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>("http://127.0.0.1/angularCRUDservices/user/getEmployees");
   }

}
```

4. app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RestAPIServices} from './services/rest-api.service';
import {Employee} from './models/employee.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  listEmployee : Employee[];
  title = 'simple-rest-app';

  constructor(private _employeeService:RestAPIServices){}
  ngOnInit(){

    this._employeeService.getEmployee().subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data)
        this.listEmployee = data;
      }
    )

    console.log(this.listEmployee);
  }

}
```

servire is tested from postman and it's working fine

```
{"response":[{"id":"1","name":"Anand","gender":"Male","email":"a@gmail.com","mobile":"111111111","department":"2","isActive":"1","photo":"assets\/images\/emp1.jpg"},{"id":"2","name":"Kiran","gender":"Female","email":"k@gmail.com","mobile":"2222222222","department":"2","isActive":"1","photo":"assets\/images\/emp1.jpg"},{"id":"3","name":"Ravi","gender":"Male","email":"r@gmail.com","mobile":"3333333333","department":"2","isActive":"1","photo":"assets\/images\/emp2.jpg"},{"id":"4","name":"Kumar","gender":"Male","email":"k@gmail.com","mobile":"4444444444","department":"3","isActive":"1","photo":"assets\/images\/emp4.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: this.listEmployee = data.response;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the server response is an object, but not an array.

```js
// try to replace
this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(...);

// by
this.httpClient.get<{ response: Employee[] }>(...).pipe(
  map(response => response.response)
);
```